# What is the FreeBSD equivalent of Windows "netstat 1"

Tags: freebsd, netstat

What is the FreeBSD equivalent of Windows **netstat 1** (displays the selected statistics again every 1 second)?

Answer (score 1):

I think, `systat -ifstat 1` is what you are looking for. See `man systat` for more information about this command.